# Is it improper, and if so why, to pass $scope to a service in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Are there strong reasons one should not pass $scope to a service?

I realize services are to be **reusable singletons** and so passing a (potentially) large object to the service might have maintenance issues, but let's assume solid documentation that would declare "the following members of $scope are required."  I just think it looks cleaner than passing in 4-6 parameters.

Any other concerns for this practice would be greatly appreciated.  I am being evaluated on this piece of code! :)

Incidentally, I JUST realized how active the angularJS community is on here and I am very grateful!!

Comment: $scope is a view/controller concern, service/factory is a business concern. By cleanly separating the two concerns, it keeps your components more modular, more testable, and loosely coupled. Usually $scope introduces a lot of needless complexity in your business layer for not a lot of benefit - but every app is different and there are exceptions to the rule.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read this article
[5 Guidelines For Avoiding Scope Soup in Angular](http://www.technofattie.com/2014/03/21/five-guidelines-for-avoiding-scope-soup-in-angular.html)

In point 5, he explains the reason for not passing $scope to Services.

I will quote some of his writing here

> The problem with relying on values to be set from a parent controller, or relying on a child controller to set data back up on the parent scope, is that you end up with an implicit coupling that isn't easy to see at first.
>
> Worse, it means the controller implementation is completely dependent on the ordering of the bindings in the view! I can't use or test those controllers independently of each other, because they are coupled together by $scope.

$scope should be used as a glue between View andController. If you want to send some value from $scope to a service, just extract those values out and pass them to the service.

If you see that you are having to pass too many values, consider grouping the values in objects and then passing them.

Changing few things in $scope, might affect your app in unwanted ways.

It is an anti-pattern to use $scope outside controllers.